# GWT (eclipse) - only seeing static html in welcome page

Tags: gwt

Surely very basic, but I am a server-side/pure java developer, just started with GWT...

My new GWT project was working just fine, until it stopped - now the welcome page is served, but I only see the static html on it and nothing else. I see no error anywhere, I can see that the js file is built and referenced from the html, Same happens with the sample web app that's created in a new project in eclipse - it is the Web application starter project - I see "enter you name:" on the browser and nothing else.

Would someone save my sanity?

Comment: Is this in DevMode or prod mode? Is there any error in your browser's console (Firebug / Firefox console, Chrome Developer Tools, IE Developer Tools, Opera DragonFly, Safari Web Inspector, etc.)

Comment: It is in both. Will check the browser console (did not try before - as a server side developer, I am not familiar with this end of things...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait longer if you've really all right and no any exceptions or errors are thrown. The fact that the static HTML is displayed immediately but compiling your Java code takes some time.

Comment: Thanks. When it worked it indeed took time; does not seem the be the case anymore...  Any hint on how to debug this at all?

Comment: Use the [Hosted mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging) for testing and development. This greatly accelerates the development. And use [Compile Report](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport) if you want to understand how the process of compiling is performing and time is spending. This'll help you identify areas requiring optimization.

Comment: Managed to get a sample project to work, but can't say I know how... I suspect something around the build in eclipse and the location of files (js) ? - but not clear. If I will have any better understanding will post...  Andrey and Thomas, thanks so much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this a few times (very rarely indeed) when there was an error in the generated files. The typical "Project > Clean..." alone is not enough with GWT projects. Here's the full process I have used to resolve this:

1. Make a backup of your files.
2. Delete the following directories (either through the "Navigator" view in Eclipse, or with an external file browser)

   - gwt-unitCache
   - war/*mymodulename*
   - war/WEB-INF/classes
   - war/WEB-INF/deploy
3. Refresh the project (right click it, choose Refresh)
4. Finally use Project > Clean...