# Can't deploy GWT application on Tomcat 7 and Jboss 7

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, tomcat, jboss

I have deployed a gwt application, and it works fine on dev Mode, but when I try to upload it on Tomcat, or Jboss, I get always the 404 page despide the server is on.
I tried to enter: `http://localhost:8080/gwtexample ,  http://localhost:8080/gwtexample/index.html and`127.0.0.1:8080/gwrexample` without  succes.

I put the war file under jboss/standalone/deployment
and under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT

```
and here is my web.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
 <param-name>symbolMapsDirectory</param-name>
<param-value>WEB-INF/classes/symbolMaps/</param-value>
   </init-param>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>BfiWebTop.html</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: Which URL works in dev mode? What's the name of the .war file?

Comment: Can you share your web.xml?

Comment: This URL works fine on dev mode : `http://127.0.0.1:8888/BfiWebTop.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 `

Comment: The name of the war is webtop.war

Comment: If you put the webtop.war in `.../webapps/`, and use `http://localhost:8080/webtop/` or `http://localhost:8080/webtop/BfiWebTop.html`, then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The war-file should be placed directly into the webapps `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps` folder. The ROOT-folder is a webapplication as well.

Please take a look at your warfile:

```
warfile/<hostpage>.html    //maybe index.html
warfile/webtop/ *          //lots of HTML or JS files with silly names (GWT stongnames)
warfile/WEB-INF/web.xml    
warfile/WEB-INF/classes/ * //your compiled server classes
warfile/WEB-INF/lib/ *     //your libraries (including gwt)
```

Comment: How did you create the web-wrchive? Maybe, there is something missing. Are there any logfiles? A tomcat will create a stdout.log or a catalina.out (.log?).

Comment: NB :the name of my project is dynamicWebtop, but I called the war webtop

Comment: what can I post exactly?

Comment: If your jbass / tomcat start, it will write a logfile. It may be saved as stdout.log or catalina.out Open this file an look for your web archive. If the auto deploy mechanism finds this file, it writes into this log.

Comment: The dev mode does not show any message, and the server Jboss starts in a normal way, but it seems he does not know about the existence of the war file .By the way, I heard about the folder WebContent but I don't have this folder in my project tree, I have war->META-INF and WEB-INF and the webtop directory which contains the cache.As I said right now, the title of my project is "dynamicWebtop" and I called the war file webtop, and the generated folder under WEB-INF is called webtop, that's the same name as <module rename-to="webtop"> on my .gwt.xml

Answer (score 1):

Today I ran into the same problem and found a solution. Since I stumbled during my research over this unanswered question, I want to share the solution that worked for me - even though the question is a few month old now.

My environment: `Eclipse Kepler SR1, GWT SDK 2.5.1, Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3`

My problem situation:

- created a `GWT` project using the `Google` plugin wizard `"New Web Application Project"`
- created a `"Hello World"` greeting
- ran it in `GWT development mode` -> `Right-mouse-click` on project folder, choose `"Run as"->"Web Application"`.

This worked fine. Now I wanted to run the `"Hello World"` application on the `Tomcat 7 server`, for which I have created a server profile in `Eclipse` before earlier. This ended with a `404` as described in this question. Here is how I tried to create and deploy the war file of the application:

- Use the `Google plugin wizard` "GWT Compile Project..." to compile the project into a war folder
- Make the `GWT` projec a dynamic web project in order to have it deployable on `Tomcat -> Right-mouse-click` on project folder, choose `"Properties"->"Project Facets"` and enable `"Dynamic Web Module".`
- `Right-mouse-click` on project folder, choose `"Run as"->"Run on Server"` and choose the `Tomcat Server` I have configured for `Eclipse`
- `Eclipse` opens the embedded browser with a `404`

I encountered the same error, when I exported the war file of the project and deployed it to the webapps folder of the `Tomcat 7` installation outside `Eclipse`.

Here is what went wrong. When I have looked into the war file itself, I found only an empty `WebContet` folder skeleton with a `META-INF` and `WEB-INF` folder. No `JavaScript` files, no `HTML files`, no `web.xml`, etc.

In order to create a correctly filled war file I had to manipulate the project properties once again.

- `Right-mouse-click` on project folder, choose `"Properties"->Deployment Assembly"`
- Remove the entry with `WebContent` source
- Add an entry with the war folder as the source:

  - Click `"Add"` button
  - Choose `"Folder"` and click `"Next"` Button
  - Choose war folder from list and click `"Finish"`

Now `"Run As"->"Run on Server"` worked.

Hope this will help someone else also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deploy your war thorugh the Admin Console of JBoss 7 ("Runtime" tab -> "Manage Deployments" -> "Add Content"). Then you can get some exceptions explaining what is wrong with your war.

Comment: well, now I can deploy the project, but it only shows me the HTML page and not the gwt widgets. This happens when I run on dev mode and on Jboss too. I did exactely the same things as here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648978/gwt-eclipse-only-seeing-static-html-in-welcome-page] but unfortunately.How can I fix this?

Comment: as someone said before, it would be nice to see some logs. Check your browser javascript-console maybe there are some errors? check the output console from the Dev mode.